# Recreate using css

Tags: html, css

So I have this menu separator http://screencast.com/t/ouOGu9Qf9p71 which in photoshop are two lines with diffrent collors.I tried something like this:

```
li:after{content:"|"}
```

But I don't know how to style it, to create that double effect, mabe using shadows :-? can someone give me a hint.

Comment: If it's a block element, give the left border one color and the right border another color. When the blocks are next to each other you should get that effect.

Comment: what about using a element with width:1px with the first color which has border-right:1px and second color?

Comment: @j08691 List elements are block elements by default. You should make that your answer, because that is the way to do it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the left border one color and the right border another color. When the blocks are next to each other you should get that effect.